# when requiring my mongoose model into utlit.js file I am getting a Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webpack

I am using React along with mongoose to generate a new user via a form. Everything is find until I try to require const CreateUser = require('../models/users.js'); into my file. I get this error. Further google searches have pointed me toward a webpack error, however not sure what to edit to make it function. Everything works fine if I just comment out the require, but with it, my server compiles without error, but doesn't load the page.

```html
bundle.js:60371 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:60371)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:60568)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:60257)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:59882)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:59036)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:59870)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:59015)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:67877)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:68087)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:67000)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:66600)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:65573)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:62495)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:62503)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:47664)
    at Object.module.exports (bundle.js:50288)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:47628)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:45470)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:45598)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:45431)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:45406)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:45156)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:20595)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:57)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:40
    at bundle.js:43
```

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  history: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Trips'}]
});

const CreateUser = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

module.exports = CreateUser;
```

```js
const CreateUser = require('../models/users.js');
const axios = require('axios');


module.exports = {
  postSignupInfo: (firstname, lastname, email, password, username) => {
    const newSignup = new CreateUser({
      firstName: firstname,
      lastName: lastname,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      username: username
    });

    newSignup.save().then(function() {
      console.log('new user was saved!');
    })
  }
};
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

//NPM Install that "tells the plugin to add any JavaScript into the bootom of the page...
// just before the closing body tag"
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  })]
}
```

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem when I started to learn react.js.  I was trying to access the database from the front end, when I moved the code server side the problem disappeared.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)